# cvs2svn output is missing files

Tags: cvs2svn

I've recently converted a CVS repo using cvs2svn however I'm confused as to the output. After running the tool, it appears it successfully ran, but there's no files in my SVN.

Here's the output from the tool after it ran.. it looks good.  However when I go to my repo.. there's nothing there.

```
cvs2svn Statistics:
------------------
Total CVS Files:             24858
Total CVS Revisions:         63124
Total CVS Branches:           9801
Total CVS Tags:             605507
Total Unique Tags:             151
Total Unique Branches:          13
CVS Repos Size in KB:      4081211
Total SVN Commits:           14506
First Revision Date:    Sun Dec 18 13:40:30 2005
Last Revision Date:     Fri Dec 26 17:09:30 2014
------------------
Timings (seconds):
------------------
 303   pass1    CollectRevsPass
   3   pass2    CleanMetadataPass
   0   pass3    CollateSymbolsPass
1085   pass4    FilterSymbolsPass
   1   pass5    SortRevisionsPass
   5   pass6    SortSymbolsPass
 135   pass7    InitializeChangesetsPass
  36   pass8    BreakRevisionChangesetCyclesPass
  33   pass9    RevisionTopologicalSortPass
  65   pass10   BreakSymbolChangesetCyclesPass
  93   pass11   BreakAllChangesetCyclesPass
  86   pass12   TopologicalSortPass
  84   pass13   CreateRevsPass
  19   pass14   SortSymbolOpeningsClosingsPass
   3   pass15   IndexSymbolsPass
1762   pass16   OutputPass
3713   total
```

My output directory looks like this:

README.txt  conf  db  format  hooks  locks

The readme says:

This is a Subversion repository; use the 'svnadmin' tool to examine it.  Do not add, delete, or modify files here unless you know how to avoid corrupting the repository.

But there's no files in it.  When I try to use TortiseSVN I get the error "Redirect cycle detected for URL"

Answer (score 0):

SVN doesn't work like a CVS repository, it's based on a database, so you cannot see exploring your directory where are the files, if you're on the machine where your svn repository is located, try to do the next:

```
svn ls file://path/to/your/repo
```

In your command line, and you will see the data on your repository, you can explore it by using ls with any path inside the repository for example.